# Loops to put string in dictionary order

Tags: c

I have this C code:

```
int main()
{
    char str[10];
    int i,j;

    printf("Enter a string\n");
    scanf("%s",str);
    printf("Your string: %s\n", str);
    for (i=0; i<str[i];i++){
        for (j = i+1; i < str[j]; j++){
            if (str[j] < str[i]){
                char temp = str[i];
                str[i]=str[j];
                str[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Your ordered string: %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

The output reverses the user-inputted string. I have 2 questions:

1. How does expression 2 in the for loop (`i<str[i]`) mean that it runs until null? If `str[0] = 0`, shouldn't it end the loop prematurely?
2. For the 2nd for loop, if I change expression 2 from `j<str[j]` to `i<str[j]`, it still works. Why is that?

Thank you!

Comment: Please mark the best answer as accepted. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

> How does expression 2 in the for loop `(i<str[i])` mean that it runs until null? If `str[0]` = `0`, shouldn't it end the loop prematurely?

It does not mean that. It means that it runs until `i` is equal to or bigger than `str[i]`. If you want to runt the loop until `str[i]` is `'\0'`, then use condition `str[i] != '\0'`, or simply just `str[i]`. In practice, your condition "works" only for short strings, and the condition itself makes no sense at all.

The reason it "works" is because for short strings, `i` will be smaller than any printable character for short strings. If you have a longer string and `str[100]` = `'a'`, then `i<str[i]` will evaluate to false, since `'a'` = `97`.

> For the 2nd for loop, if I change expression 2 from `j<str[j]` to `i<str[j]`, it still works. Why is that?

For the same reason as why the above works. In most cases both `j < str[j]` and  `i < str[j]` are false only when you hit the `\0`-terminator. At least this is true for short strings.

Change the declaration of `str` to `char str[200]` and try longer input. You'll notice that neither of your versions will work at all.

Here is some proper code that makes sense and works, and it stops working when changing `j<str[j]` to `i<str[j]`:

```
int len = strlen(str);
for (i=0; i<len; i++){
    for (j = i+1; j < len; j++){
        if (str[j] < str[i]){
            char temp = str[i];
            str[i]=str[j];
            str[j]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```